# Interactive altair chart that can change between monthly and yearly aggregates

Tags: interactive, altair, aggregates

I have a time series dataset and I wanted to plot line charts that display monthly and yearly changes.Some code provided below as an example. But instead of making two static charts, I'd like to have one interactive chart that allows me to change toggle between yearly and monthly chart by clicking radio buttons. I am not sure if this is possible.

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.stocks()

base = alt.Chart(source).encode(
x=alt.X('date:T',axis=alt.Axis(format="%Y-%b",grid=False)),
y=alt.Y('price:Q'),
color='symbol:N'
 )

lines = base.mark_line().encode()
lines
```

[image]

```
source = data.stocks()
source['year']=source.date.dt.year

base = alt.Chart(source).encode(
x='year:N',
y='avg_price:Q',
color='symbol:N'
).transform_aggregate(
                avg_price='mean(price)',
                groupby=['symbol','year'])

points = base.mark_line().encode(
opacity=alt.value(1)
).properties(
width=600
)
points
```

[image]